# ggplot2 Comparison Boxplots For Continous X,Y,Z Data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate and modify the following plot:

[image: Plot]

which compares boxplots of continuous x,y,z, data by binning Z into two bins with equal numbers of values and x into 5 bins with equal amounts of observations. Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(y=sample(seq( 0,500, by = 0.1), 1000, replace = T),x=sample(seq( 0,600, by = 0.1), 1000, replace = T),z=sample(seq( 0,1, by = 0.1), 1000, replace = T))
xbins<-as.numeric(cut_number(df$x,5))
zbins<-as.numeric(cut_number(df$z,2))
```

The color choice is not important and I don't need the number of observations in each bin, since mine will have equal amounts of values.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `interaction()` for your grouping variable to calculate distributions for combinations of x and z

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes(xbins, y, fill=factor(zbins), group=interaction(xbins, zbins)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MrFlick's answer is exactly what I am looking for, but for completeness here is the code with x axis labels and a legend to match my example plot:

```
ggplot(df) +
aes(xbins, y, fill=factor(zbins), group=interaction(xbins, zbins)) +
geom_boxplot() + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,600)) + xlab('x') + ylab('y')+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:5,
                 labels=c("0-117.8", "117.9-229.8", "229.9-349.6","349.7-484.7","484.7-600")) +
scale_fill_discrete(name = 'z',labels = c("< 0.5", ">.5"))+
theme(legend.position = c(0.1,0.9),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"))
```

which creates:

[image: Output Plot]